# I can not find a definition for require_auth2, what does this do and how?

Tags: dapp, eosio-code

require_auth2 is used in **action.hpp**'s **require_auth**.

```
void require_auth(const permission_level& level) {
    require_auth2( level.actor, level.permission );
}
```

require_auth2 is declared in action.h.

```
void require_auth2( account_name name, permission_name permission );
```

I can not find a definition for **require_auth2**. Where is the definition of this? What logic does it handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What does it do:**

With **`require_auth2`** you are specifying both the **account name** and the **permission** level you need.

You would call `require_auth2` as follows:

```
    require_auth2(account_name, N(permission));
```

Where `permission` can be `owner`, `active`, or some other permission that you may have configured for this account.

**`require_auth` is a shortcut to:**

```
     require_auth2(account_name, N(active));
```

---

**Where is it defined:**

`require_auth2` *appears* to be defined via [REGISTER_INTRINSICS](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/90fefdd12a4797e47890910f11dd7b60f1435ed4/libraries/chain/wasm_interface.cpp#L1796)
and eventually it calls (in *apply_context.cpp*):

```
 void apply_context::require_authorization
```

But I don't have the C++ chops to understand how that works exactly.

Comment: can you give me some explanation of the  REGISTER_INTRINSICS, the macro is too difficult to understand

Answer (score 1):

require_auth2 is defined via REGISTER_INTRINSICS,it call the function of class authorization_api.
Finally,it's implemented in apply_context.require_authorization( account, permission ).

The macro REGISTER_INTRINSICS is apply for compiler intrinsics,it expand to:

```
_REGISTER_INTRINSIC(r,authorization_api,(require_authorization, void(int64_t, int64_t), "require_auth2", void(authorization_api::*)(const account_name&, const permission_name& permission) ))
```

According to args number,continue to expand to:

```
_REGISTER_INTRINSIC4(authorization_api,MOD,require_authorization,void(int64_t, int64_t),"require_auth2",void(authorization_api::*)(const account_name&, const permission_name& permission))(authorization_api,"env",(require_authorization, void(int64_t, int64_t), "require_auth2", void(authorization_api::*)(const account_name&, const permission_name& permission) ))
```

Eventually,choose wavm or binaryen compiler to process it.